# What is wrong with my AS2 button code?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I was to just put a button component and the script below for the page to go back to home when pressed:

```
stop();
gallery_btn.onRelease = function (){
        getURL(&quot;http://chopsticks-cutlery.de &quot;);
}
```

For some reason, it's giving the following error messages below
(kindly click on this link: http://i429.photobucket.com/albums/qq19/tsujzpie/urltobuttoncodeproblems.jpg)

Don't know why this is happening - it is supposed to be  a simple script to work quickly error-free right?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `&quot;` but it is wrong.
Use this code:

```
stop();
gallery_btn.onRelease = function (){
        getURL("http://chopsticks-cutlery.de");
}
```

Comment: Christ! Was that it?! Thanks so much!